# Script not working only in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, filter

I have a script that basically is a search/filter that runs all browsers except firefox. And I dont know what is wrong. I'm trying since saturday find what is wrong, searching here if someone had the same problem and nothing. I'm LEARNING javascript, so I'm hoping someone can point me into the right direction to find what i'm not doing right or what i'm missing. Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccarizzo/GYcbE/

online [here](http://coolla.com.br/carizzo/filtroteste/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as you can tell by looking in the error console, is this code:

```
$(listaProdutos).find('a:Contains(' + filter + ')').parent();
```

There is no "listaProdutos" variable in the script.  You're relying on a non-standard behavior in other browsers that reflects all IDs into the global scope.

This should work:

```
$("listaProdutos").find('a:Contains(' + filter + ')').parent();
```

You need a similar change in some other places too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check interoperability of your web-scripts.

[Click here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://coolla.com.br/carizzo/filtroteste/) to get yours validated.

Comment: already did that, after the changes of the validator it's not working at all :( I have no idea of what this could be. :/